# Replace the blue-gray stripes background in a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I replace the vertical blue-gray stripes background in a grouped UITableView?
For example, it would be cool to have a background of horizontal stripes instead!

Here is a nice example:

[image: Like this one]
<sub>(source: [pessoal.org](http://pessoal.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/primary.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changing the backgroundColor on the tableView should work

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Comment: Great thx! I made the background solid red but had no idea that it was possible to create a "color" from an image!

Comment: Yip, colorWithPatternImage is a great feature :)

Comment: you have missed colon(:) in your answer

Comment: the method should be

tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];